# is there a Map on Java that don't clone value when get()

Tags: java, dictionary

We have known, value of element will be clone when we get it from a Map, such as:

```
        Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap();        
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        //put
        map.put("id1", obj);
        //get
        MyObject obj1 = map.get("id1"); 
        MyObject obj2 = map.get("id1"); //"obj2" is only a clone of "obj1"

        //change some things
        obj1.setName("AAA");
        obj2.setName("BBB");

        //show: they are different
        obj1.printName(); //Print: AAA
        obj2.printName(); //Print: BBB
```

But, i want a Map that return **original instance**, is there kind of Map  like that?

```
        Map<String, MyObject> map = new AUnknownMap();        
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        //put
        map.put("id1", obj);
        //get
        MyObject obj1 = map.get("id1"); 
        MyObject obj2 = map.get("id1"); //"obj2" and "obj1" refer the same instance

        //change some things
        obj1.setName("AAA");
        obj2.setName("BBB");

        //show: they are the same
        obj1.printName(); //Print: BBB
        obj2.printName(); //Print: BBB
```

Comment: Maps already don't clone the object they return. They should operate as in your second example.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, i have just returned with Java (after doing some works with C++). It have changed very much. thank you, all body!

Answer (score 7):

> We have known, value of element will be clone when we get it from a Map

No, it won't. It's unclear exactly how you're seeing your original output, but that's *not* the normal behaviour.

Here's a short but complete example based on your code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class MyObject {
   private String name;

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public void printName() {
       System.out.println(name);
   }
}

class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
       MyObject obj1 = new MyObject();
       map.put("id1", obj1);
       MyObject obj2 = map.get("id1");

       obj1.setName("AAA");
       obj2.setName("BBB");

       obj1.printName();
       obj2.printName();
   }
}
```

This prints "BBB" twice, contrary to the claim in the question.

Presumably you've got code *a bit like* your sample code, which produces the different output that we can't reproduce with the code you *have* provided. You should examine your real code closely to work out where the difference is between that and what you've provided. No cloning occurs by default with any of the standard collections.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, i have just returned with Java (after do some works with C++). It have changed very much. thank you, all body!

Comment: @Deka: When you say "It have changed very much" - Java hasn't changed at all in this respect. If you mean "Java is very different to C++" then you're right... and you should always validate your assumptions.

Comment: I create this question because a my friend has gotten the same error with his project (and tell me) in last year, he have used Java 6. Because that, i think the reason is Java flat-form. But now, i think it is another reason